# wpf style ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames animate child element

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard

I have a button (or rather something derived from Button) containing a grid which in turn contains an image and four labels.

I want to conditionally animate the button, changing foreground and background colors to make it blink.

This works just fine for the background, but not for the labels' foreground.

Style:

```
<Style x:Key="RequestButtonStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultButtonStyle}" TargetType="local:CADButton">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Priority}" Value="1">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard 
                                RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                Duration="0:0:1.5">
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(local:CADButton.Background).Color">
                                    <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{StaticResource EmergencyCallColor}"/>
                                    <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.75" Value="{StaticResource DefaultButtonBackgroundColor}"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                    <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{StaticResource DefaultButtonForegroundPressedColor}"/>
                                    <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.75" Value="{StaticResource DefaultButtonForegroundColor}"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>                         
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

How do I target any labels inside the button?

I tried at some point to bind the Labels' foreground to the Button's foreground (and then I just set "foreground" rather than "something.Foreground"). That worked to some degree. Problem is, I have a style on the labels that changes the colors on mouseover. Once that is done, the binding is overwritten, and the blinking stops.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I target any labels inside the button?

You cannot do this from a trigger in your RequestButtonStyle because a Style Setter can only set a property of the type that is being applied to, i.e. a property of the CADButton itself in this case.

If you want to animate a property of a Label in the Buttons's ControlTemplate you need to define another Style for the Label itself and apply it to the Label. Or you could bind the Foreground property of the Label to the Foreground property of the parent Button and animate this property. This would be the easiest and best solution so you should probably try to move the trigger that changes the Label's colours on mouse over to the ControlTemplate or the Style of the Button.

Comment: I tried both. Tying it to the Foreground of the button worked until the first MouseOver, which also changed the text.
When I made a "standalone style" for the Label, the first mouseover also stopped the animation

Comment: You still cannot set a property of the Label in the Button Style so please provide a reproducible sample of your issue including all relevant XAML markup and code snippets if you need any further help...